# jQuery Mobile: checkbox in collapsbile header cannot be checked more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

On my jQuery Mobile website (1.4.5), in my collapsible header I use a checkbox. The following code almost works perfectly, my problem is that an unchecked checkbox can only be checked and rechecked once. Checking it again (= third click) is not possible. I don't see the problem:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="collapsibleSetWrapper" data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>
           <span>some title</span>
           <input class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" id="uniqueID"/>
           <label for="uniqueID">Click me</label>
        </h3>
        <div id="mycontent">
              <p>this is the content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#collapsibleSetWrapper .mycheckbox').checkboxradio({
            create: function(event,ui){
                var checkbox = $(event.target);
                var clickTarget = $(event.target).parent();
                $(clickTarget).click(function(e){
                    console.log(checkbox);

                    if($(checkbox).is(':checked')){
                        $(checkbox).attr("checked",false).checkboxradio('refresh');
                        // select all the nested checkboxes here
                    }
                    else{
                        $(checkbox).attr("checked",true).checkboxradio('refresh');
                        // unselect all the nested checkboxes here
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the click handler on the label.ui-btn DOM element that jQM creates instead of the parent DIV. Also use prop() instead of attr():

```
$('#collapsibleSetWrapper .mycheckbox').on("checkboxradiocreate", function (event, ui) {
    var checkbox = $(event.target);
    var clickTarget = $(event.target).closest(".ui-checkbox").find("label.ui-btn");
    $(clickTarget).on("click", function (e) {
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            checkbox.prop("checked", false).checkboxradio('refresh');
            // select all the nested checkboxes here
        } else {
            checkbox.prop("checked", true).checkboxradio('refresh');
            // unselect all the nested checkboxes here
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6t7bhbgc/)**